# Deploy Angular 4 App on centOS Server

Tags: angular, apache, centos7

I want to deploy my Angular 4 Application on my centOS Server. It's the first time i did it, so I already installed apache on it, because many threads talked about it. I already know that i have to do `ng build --prod` to make a `dist` file that my webserver can show, but how can I push the dist file to my server? My code is in a git repository and I want to build and deploy my app with jenkins. Have someone experience with deployment?

Answer (score 0):

In your apache directory say inside webapp since I am using tomcat
create a folder say proj

After building the angular project

copy "..........\angproj\dist" to proj folder

copy "..........\angproj\i18n" to proj folder

After that access the index file like so
http://apache-host/proj/#/